# Hash Password not generated Node Js

Tags: node.js

i am beginner of nodejs and mongodb. i am creating login api using node js i tried to add the password hash but couldn't inserted.what is wrong on this code can you check out. i attached the below of the Model.

**Model**

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    var Schema  = mongoose.Schema;
    
    
    var studentSchema = new Schema(
        {
            name: {
                    type:String,
                    required: true
            },
            address: {
                type:String,
                required: true
            },
            phone: {
                type:Number,
                required: true
            },
            password:{
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                required : true
            }
    
        }
    )
    
    
     studentSchema.pre("save",async function(next){
        const student = this;
     if(user.isModified("password"))
     {
        student.password = await bcrypt.hash(student.password,8)
    }
     next()
    
     })
 module.exports =mongoose.model('student',studentSchema);
```

How to create the Student Records i attached code below

**Add Student**

```
router.post('/student/create', async(req,res)=>{
   
    const student = new studentModel(req.body)
    try{
            await student.save();
            res.status(201).send(
                {
                    "status" : true,
                    "message" : "Student Created!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
                });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        res.status(400).send(error);

    }


});
```

Comment: can you share the other relevant code ([mcve])?